# pass object in mutation

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo

GraphQl server is working fine when i send the mutation in graphiql but im stuck in the client side how can i send the array in graphql mutation using apollo angular.

**Working mutation**

```
mutation{cashBillsAddBulk(CashBills:[{
billValue:1,registerId:2,registerStatus:"open"
  ,billCount:1},{
billValue:1,registerId:2,registerStatus:"open"
  ,billCount:1}])}
```

**Client-side mutation**

```
 const cashBillsAddBulk = gql`mutation ($bills: [CashBillsInput]){cashBillsAddBulk(CashBills: $bills)}
```

`;

**function**

```
public addCashBills(CashBills: any[]): Observable<any> {
return this.apollo.mutate({
mutation: cashBillsAddBulk,
variables: CashBills
});
```

}

Comment: Looks like you are on the right track. Have you tried the mutation you wrote in JavaScript in GraphiQL? It has another input where you can encode the variables in JSON.
If that does not help you verify if the problem is GraphQL, can you post the error message you are getting?

Comment: resposne: {"data":{"cashBillsAddBulk":null},"errors":[{"message":"Cannot read property 'length' of undefined","locations":[{"line":2,"column":3}],"path":["cashBillsAddBulk"]}]}

Comment: Ah okay, the variable is undefined (small tip, make it required in your GraphQL schema and variable definition: `mutation ($bills: [CashBillsInput!]!)`. I see the problem now, variables must itself be an object again:
`this.apollo.mutate({ mutation: cashBillsAddBulk, variables: { bills: CashBills } })`

Comment: i dont know but in request payload the operation name is NULL and now 
"message":"Validation error"

Comment: Operation name `null` is fine (your mutation does not have a name but this is perfectly valid if it is the only mutation). What exactly the validation error is is hard to say. Maybe this was triggered by making the `$bills` variable required?

Comment: how can i debug that?

Comment: Maybe see if the resolver get's called at all. Also a validation error should normally be a bit more descriptive... Is there a path and a stack that comes with the error?